# Split every two words from string using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm able to split every words from string using below code:

```
string s = TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToString(); // a b c d e f g h 
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    TextBox1.Text += "\n"+word.ToString();
}
```

this code return output like
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h

i want to split every two words like this

a b
b c
c d
d e
e f
f g
g h

Comment: What about a counter variable? You could check if it is `% 2 == 0` and decide what to do based on that... Which basically means adding a linebreak or just a space.

Comment: You don't need `ToString()` as `Trim()` acts on a string and returns a string

Comment: In case if you already using [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#pairwise), it can be done in a single line: `s.Split(' ').Pairwise((a, b) => $"{a} {b}");`

Comment: You also don't need the `word.ToString()` since `word` is already a `string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to convert your foreach to a for loop and use index

```
string s = TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToString(); //a b c d e f g h 
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
{
    TextBox1.Text += $"\n{words[i]} {words[i + 1]}";
}
```

if we have "a b c" it will show

```
a b
b c
```

and if we have "a b c d"

```
a b
b c
c d
```

Comment: use just one word !

Comment: @nAviD I edit my answer to show example, it will work with odd

Comment: @nAviD failing for one word is different than failing for any odd number of words (3 5 7 9 etc works just fine)

Comment: @Rafalon you said :"I don't think so". Now it seems that NOW you do think so !

Comment: @Rafalon While it doesn't really belong to the solution of the exact problem, it would improve the answer if it notified OP he should fortify against unexpected split results (like count = 0, 1 or null), wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score -2):

The best way is to use `Regex` (Regular Expressions):

```
        foreach(var s in (new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[^ ]+ [^ ]+")).Matches("a b c d e f"))
TextBox1.Text += s.ToString()+"\n";
```

you can see the result here :

https://dotnetfiddle.net/rJ8NEQ

Comment: @Rafalon me I think ?

Comment: what makes you think it isn't ? tell your reasons ! @Rafalon

Comment: I never claimed that it was better or worse than anything, *you did*. That's why I wanted to know if there was a reason

Comment: You question it being the best ! so what are your reasons?

Comment: I just asked you to back up your assumptions. Do you have anything personal against me? Did I offend you in the past?

Comment: Also, your solution doesn't fit OP requirements (the second word is not repeated) AND it fails for one word exactly as Guilhem's do. More than that, it does *indeed* fail for any odd number of words