# How do I output every other word in a string?

Tags: c#, string

I am new to C# and only know the basics. I'm looking for a code example on how I would get every other word from a string variable. For example if the variable was

```
String x = "Help me, coding is difficult";
```

I would want to return single string "Help coding difficult". It needs to be a function that takes one string and return filtered version of it.

Someone suggested duplicates that I mostly already seen during my research:

- [How to split text into words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725848/how-to-split-text-into-words) shows very complicated logic that takes into account punctuation for example. I think I'm fine just to rely on spaces, but if you have better suggestion with an explanation - would be nice.
- [Select every second element from array using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082913/select-every-second-element-from-array-using-lambda) - seems promising, but sample shows how to work with integer array. I have string (or maybe string array if one can adapt string splitting code to provide one).
- [C# Print list of string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112051/c-sharp-print-list-of-string-array) that also sounds promising but it shows how to *print* the result, not how to return it as value from a function.

Comment: How do you define the boundary between a word? If `me,` was the first word, would you include or exclude the comma?

Comment: Preferably Exclude the comma which i think could be done using .split if im not mistaken?

Comment: Unless you can constrain the text in some known way, or are comfortable with lots of bugs around edge cases, you're on the wrong side of this comic: https://xkcd.com/1425/ and what you're asking for is the equivalent of a fully functional natural language processor.

Comment: What about punctuation? Or apostrophes? Or hyphens? ["What counts as a Word?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8niIHChc1Y) is hard to describe, unless you're simply doing "a space is the only thing that counts".

Comment: So if I was to leave the punctuation in with the word output and only exclude the spaces. is there a way to skip the 2nd, 4th, 6th word and so on and only output the 1st , 3rd, 5th, and so on?

Comment: If you're just looking to strip out the punctuation, and split on spaces, then yes `string.Split` is the right direction, followed by something like a `for` loop. We *can* answer these kinds of questions, but I think you would be better suited following some tutorials first, and ask here once you have an attempted implementation

Comment: What should happen to this sentence? `"Help me!Coding is difficult"`?

Comment: A strategy might be to replace punctuation marks with spaces, remove multiple spaces and then use an alternate selector as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123685/how-to-get-alternate-elements-using-enumerable-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If upvoter can [edit] the question with clarifications requested in comment it would be nice (and possibly even it will no longer need list of duplicates I suggested).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think every 2nd word is not the same as every 2nd element as suggested by your duplicate.

Comment: @Magnus sounds fair - I've edited the question to add clarifications how none of the duplicates helped (or even if they are related)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split every two words from string using asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807078/split-every-two-words-from-string-using-asp-net-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you count a word as "every character between spaces, or the start/end of the string", and you're not trying to remove any letters.

```
var input = "Help me, coding is difficult";
var everyOther = input
    .Split(' ')
    .Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", everyOther));
```

The code for the `Where` was taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682615/how-can-i-get-every-nth-item-from-a-listt).

The idea is to use the overload of `Where` which gives you the index value, and see if that index value is even, if so, include it in the results.

Comment: As im new to C# & coding in general... are you able to breakdown the ".Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0);" so I have a better understanding of how it works and what its doing?

Comment: Uh, well. There's a number of topics here. Linq. Lambdas. Modulus division. Those three terms should give you a starting point.

Comment: @SeanNormandale that part applies a filter to the collection, based on the index. It's syntactic sugar for `bool IsOdd(item, index) { return index % 2 == 0; }`, which is passed to the `Where` method: `.Where(IsOdd)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to define first what are word delimiters, just a space, a comma, period or semicolon or what else? Then you can use [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0).

```
char[] wordDelimiter = new[] { ' ','\t', ',', '.', '!', '?', ';', ':', '/', '\\', '[', ']', '(', ')', '<', '>', '@', '"', '\'' };
String x = "Help me, coding is difficult"; 
string[] words = x.Split(wordDelimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Now you have an array with all words. But you want every other, you could fill them into a [`List<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) and use a [`for-loop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-for-statement) that skips every other:

```
var everyOtherWord = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i += 2)
{
    everyOtherWord.Add(words[i]);
}
```

> I would want to return "Help coding difficult"

So you really want to have a `string` as result that contains these words separated by space? Then use [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0) (somehow the *counterpart* method of `String.Split`):

```
string result = string.Join(" ", everyOtherWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "You win some. You lose some.";

string[] subs = s.Split(' ');

for(int i=0 ; i < subs.length ; i+=2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Substring: {sub[i]}");
}
```